# Run C# Script on Google Cloud

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, server

Is it possible to run/compile a C# script on Google?
I know one can run C# scripts for webservers but is it also possible to do the same only with a script that is having a TCP connection?

```
 public static void Start()
    {
       
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        tcpListener.Start();
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);
     }
```

Comment: Please could you clarify exactly what you mean? What do you mean by "only with a script that is having a TCP connection"? You can run all kinds of code on GCP, in any number of ways... without more details, it's going to be very hard to give an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added some code is it now better to understand?

Comment: Not really... it's still a very broad question. You can create your own virtual machine, or you can run your own service in a GKE cluster... those can basically do whatever you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I hope that'll do and I am sorry for my unprecise question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can do it in a number of ways.
If you simply want to run the code, there is [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) and [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible).
If you'd rather have full control, you can spin a virtual machine in [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute), select OS and set up your own environment.
If you want the service to be more flexible and scalable you can set up a [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine).
It all depends on your requirements and use case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. One last question: Is the app in the App Engine or in Kubernetes always running or does it solely gets called when a client calls it?

Comment: They are always running, although App Engine has a free quota. You can estimate the cost [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=).